# Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $n$ be a positive integer. Use the Binomial Theorem to show that $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}}\not\equiv1$ (mod $p^n$).

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

**The Problem**: Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $n$ be a positive integer. Use the Binomial Theorem to show that $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}}\not\equiv1$ (mod $p^n$).

**Source**: *Abstract Algebra, $3^{rd}$ edition*, Dummit and Foote.

**My Attempt**: I have shown that $(1+p)^{p^{n-1}}\equiv1$ (mod $p^n$) for the same $p, n$ by showing that each term in the Binomial Expansion of $(1+p)^{p^{n-1}}$ is divisible by $p^n$ (except, of course, the first term). But the same approach obviously fails for the problem at hand. Instead, I tried to make use of $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}}\equiv1$ (mod $p^{n-1}$), to no avail. Finally, assuming $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}}\equiv1$ mod ($p^n$) did not give rise to a contradiction either. I am officially stuck.

There is a [relevant post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20742/506332) that involves a lemma using $p$-order $Ord_p(x)$, where $Ord_p(x)$ is the largest $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p^N|x$; but I did not find the final step in [the proof for that lemma](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400primitiveroots.pdf) convincing enough. Other relevant posts such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20743/506332) provide tools that are unnecessarily powerful. Hence this post.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Which terms of $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}}$ does the previous result work for?  Perhaps most of the terms of $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}}$ are also equivalent to zero.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Beautiful. Thank you so much!