# Prove that MCD is 1 or 3 knowing (a,b) = 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I'm don't know from where to start in this problem. I have to prove that

> $(a+b,a^2-ab+b^2)=1 \text{ or } 3$

knowing that $(a,b) = 1$.

I've tried using the method they taught us on class, so I've written that:

> $d\ |\ a+b \Rightarrow d\ | a^2 + 2ab + b^2$  and $d\ |\ a^2-ab+b^2 $
>   $\Rightarrow d\ | \ 3ab$

But from here, I dont know where to go. Usually, I should be able to  find that d divides something in terms of a, and something in terms of b, and therefore, using that $(a:b)=1$ I would get the solution. But this is not the case. Any operation I've tried between the two terms, gives me an other term, but always in terms of a and b, and no a or b, so I'm not able to prove what I'm asked.

Any ideas?

Comment: And also [If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a+b,a^2 -ab+b^2)=1$ or $3$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/257392) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/257392).