# If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ then prove that $\gcd(a+b, a^2-ab+b^2) = 1$ or $3$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ then prove that $\gcd(a+b, a^2-ab+b^2) = 1$ or $3$?

I am shamelessly asking how to solve the problem? I have no idea how to start and solve. Please help.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257392/if-gcda-b-1-then-gcdab-a2-abb2-1-or-3  or

Comment: And also [If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a+b,a^2 -ab+b^2)=1$ or $3$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/257392) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/257392).