# $\gcd\left(a+b,\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}\right)=1$, or $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $p$ be prime number ($p\gt2$) and $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ ,$a+b\neq0$ ,$\gcd(a,b)=1$ how to  prove that $$\gcd\left(a+b,\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}\right)=1~~\text{or}~~ p$$

Thanks in advance .

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721273/show-that-if-gcda-b-1-and-p-is-an-odd-prime-then, math.stackexchange.com/questions/491806/proving-gcd-m-n-1 and other questions linked there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\begin{align}&{\bf Hint}\ \  \rm\displaystyle {\left(a\!-\!b,\frac{a^p\!-b^p}{a-b}\right)} = \overbrace{(a\!-\!b,\,a^{p-1}\!+\cdots+b^{p-1}) = (a\!-\!b,\color{#C00}{pb^{p-1}})}^{\large \bmod a-b:\ \ a\ \equiv\ b} = (a\!-\!b,p)\\[.2em]  
&\rm\ \ \  by\ \ \ (a,b) = 1\:\Rightarrow\: (a\!-\!b,b) = (a,b)=1,\,\ therefore\ \,\rm (a\!-\!b,b^n) = 1\ \  by\ Euclid's\ Lemma. \end{align}$

**Remark** $\ $ It's a special case $\rm\ f(x) = x^p,\,\ x = a\ \ (so\ \ \color{#0A0}{f'(b)} = \color{#C00}{pb^{p-1}})\:$ of

**Theorem** $\rm\displaystyle\quad  \frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b} \equiv\ \color{#0A0}{f\:'(b)}\pmod {x\!-\!b}\quad$ for $\rm\ f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$

**Proof** $\ $ By Taylor, $\rm\,\ f(x)\ =\ f(b)  +\: f\:'(b)\ (x\!-\!b) \,+\, (x\!-\!b)^2\: g(x)\ \ $ for some $\rm\ g(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$

Comment: Note: this is meant as a (big) hint, along with some conceptual background for further motivation. If you have any trouble filling in the details then please feel welcome to ask questions in comments, and I will gladly elaborate.

Comment: See also [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/660329/242)

Answer (score 2):

We already now that $\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}=a^{p-1}-a^{p-2}b+\ldots+b^{p-1}$
Using polynomial division, we find that
$$a+b\,|\,a^{p-1}-a^{p-2}b+\ldots+b^{p-1}=(a^{p-2}-2a^{p-2}b+3a^{p-3}b^2-\ldots-pb^{p-2})+pb^{p-1}$$
Hence $\gcd(\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b},a+b)=\gcd(pb^{p-1},a+b)=\gcd(p,a+b)=1\text{ or } p$
as desired.