# Values of $\gcd(a-b,\frac{a^p-b^p}{a-b} )$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I don't know how to prove the following result.

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Then  $\gcd (a-b,\frac{a^p-b^p}{a-b}) = 1 $ or $ p $

(gcd should be $1$)

I know that $\dfrac{a^p-b^p}{a-b} = a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+\cdots $

I don't know what to do next...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is obviously wrong. Take $p=2, a=3, b=0$, then $\gcd(3-0, \frac{9-0}{3-0}) = 3$

Comment: Sorry I forgot the $gcd(a,b)=1$ hypothesis.

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/660329/242) for a very simple proof.

Comment: Related: [$\gcd\left(a+b,\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}\right)=1$ or $p$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340955)

Comment: And http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $a^m b^n + (a-b)a^mb^{n-1} = a^{m+1}b^{n-1}$. By applying this repeatedly we get
$$\gcd(a-b,a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+\cdots+b^{p-1}) = \gcd(a-b,pa^{p-1}).$$
Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, also $\gcd(a-b,a^{p-1})=1$ and hence
$$\gcd(a-b,pa^{p-1}) = \gcd(a-b,p),$$
which is $1$ or $p$, since $p$ is prime.