# GCD of $a+b$ and $\frac{a^p + b^p}{a+b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In Ivan Niven's book on "Introduction to the theory of numbers", there is a question in the first chapter that has been boggling me.

Given $p$ is an odd prime and $(a,b) = 1$ where $(a,b) = \gcd(a,b)$, show that
$$ \left(a+b,\frac{a^p + b^p}{a+b} \right) = 1 \mbox{ or }p$$

To gain intuition, I started with $p=3$ case. I was able to prove the result by eventually showing that the above gcd was equal to $(a+b,3)$. My guess therefore is that we should be able to show that this gcd is equal to $(a+b, k(a+b)+p(u))$ where $(u,a+b)=1$. However I have not been successful in this endeavor. Perhaps there is an alternate strategy...

I would appreciate any hints/tips/ideas on how to proceed. If I get it, i'll post my method as an answer.

Comment: Write $b^p=-(-b)^p$  and use  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247146/how-to-show-that-gcd-left-an-bn-over-a-b-a-b-right-gcdn-dn-1-a-b

Comment: @lab: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Because you ask for ***any*** hint, perhaps this small exercise for myself is helpful/interesting/leading-to-somewhere for you: http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/CyclicSubgroups_work.pdf   It discusses the (prime)-factorization of the numerators expression as well as in relation to that of the denominator.

Comment: Thanks Gottfried. It's very helpful and useful. Additionally, you might like the following: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf

Comment: Thanks Gautam - nearly the same as I'd done it but with a different flavour... I'm curious to see what's in it (and perhaps can brush my own text up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/498505/35983) which was very useful.

Observe that $a^mb^n = (a+b)a^mb^{n-1} - a^{m+1}b^{n-1}$

Now 
$$ \frac{a^p + b^p}{a+b} = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(-1)^ka^kb^{p-1-k}$$

With reference to above, note that repeated application of said result will result in 
$$\frac{a^p + b^p}{a+b} = (a+b)M + pa^{p-1}$$
where M is some integer. This can be easily verified (I did it by taking the cases where $m$ is odd and even separately and making sure I end up with $+a^{p-1}$ in all cases).

Now since $(a,b)=1 \Rightarrow (a+b,a) = 1 \Rightarrow (a+b,a^{p-1}) = 1 $ along with $(a,bc)=(a,c)$ if $(a,b)=1$ together give 
$$ \left(a+b, \frac{a^p + b^p}{a+b}\right) = (a+b,pa^{p-1})=(a+b,p)$$

QED