# Show the following if $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p$ is prime and $ a \ge 2$, prove that 
$$
d = (a - 1, \frac{a^p - 1}{a - 1}) =
\begin{cases}
p & \text{if } p \mid (a - 1)\\
1 & \text{if } p \nmid (a - 1) \, .
\end{cases}
$$

I was thinking that since $(a^p-1)/(a-1) = (a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}+...+1)$ if p divides a-1 then p should divide $(a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}+...+1)$ ??

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247146

Answer (score 3):

We find the remainder when the **polynomial** $f(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+1$ is divided by $x-1$. This is $f(1)$, which is $p$.

So the gcd of $a-1$ and $f(a)$ is the same as the gcd of $a-1$ and $p$, and we are finished.

Comment: how can you prove that the gcd of $a-1$ and $f(a)$ is the gcd between $a-1$ and $p$?

Comment: It is a general result you have probably already seen before, since it is at the basis of the Euclidean Algorithm. If $b=qa+r$, then $\gcd(b,a)=\gcd(a,r)$. I imagine you know a proof. Briefly  if $k$ divides $a$ and $b$, it divides $r$ (and $a$), and if $k$ divides $r$ and $a$ then $k$ divides $b$ (and $a$). So $a$ and $b$ and $a$ and $r$ have the same set of common divisors, and in particular the same **greatest** common divisor.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d=\gcd(a-1,\frac{a^p-1}{a-1})$, now let $q$ be a prime dividing $a-1$ and let $v_q(a-1)$ be the greatest power of $q$ dividng $a-1$,using the [lifting's exponent lemma](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h393335_lifting_the_exponent_lemma_containing_pdf_file) we have:
$$v_q\left(\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}\right)=v_q(a^p-1)-v_q(a-1)=v_q(p)$$.

- If $q\neq p$ then $v_q\left(\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}\right)=0$ then $q$ does not divide $d$.
- If $q=p$ then $v_q\left(\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}\right)=1$ so the greatest power of $p$ dividing $\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ is $p$ hence the power greatest power of $p$ dividing $d$ is $p$.

Finally $d=p$.