# $a, b, c, d$ are fixed positive integers. If $(ad - bc) \mid a$ and $(ad - bc) \mid c$, show that $\gcd(an + b, cn + d)= 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

I've tried a couple of things trying to solve this problem but I get no answer.

These are one of the few things I know about “Gcd” and division:

If $a\mid b$ and $a \mid c$, then $a \mid b \cdot x + c \cdot y$ for any $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I also know that if $a$ divides $b$ and $c$, also divides its sum and it’s subtraction.

“gcd” also represents the minor linear combination.

I’d really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: The first condition implies that $ad-bc \mid \gcd(a,c)$, but also $\gcd(a,c) \mid ad-bc$.  So $ad-bc = \pm \gcd(a,c)$, and by absorbing a common factor into $n$ we can assume WLOG that $ad-bc = \pm 1$.  Can you progress from here?

Comment: For your recent [deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3290225/242) see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/340980/242) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/660329/242), replacing $b$ by $-b\ \ $

Comment: thank you @BillDubuque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $a = x(ad-bc)$ and $c = y(ad-bc)$.  Then
$$ad-bc = [x(ad-bc)] \cdot d - b[y(ad-bc)] = (dx - by) (ad - bc).$$
However, since $(ad-bc) \mid a$, and $a$ is positive, it follows that $ad - bc \ne 0$.  Thus, we must have that $dx - by = 1$, from which we can conclude that $\gcd(b,d) = 1$ (which proves the case of $n = 0$).

Now, for the general case, note that $a(cn+d) - (an+b)c = ad-bc$ so it divides both $a$ and $c$.  Therefore, by the previous paragraph with $a' := a$, $b' := an+b$, $c' := c$, $d' := cn+d$, we get $\gcd(b', d') = 1$, i.e. $\gcd(an+b, cn+d) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you, very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g = \gcd(a,c)$. Since $g \mid a$ and $g \mid c$, we get $g \mid ad-bc$. Since $ad-bc \mid a$ and $ad-bc \mid c$, then $ad-bc$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $c$, so $ad-bc \mid g$. Now, $g \mid ad-bc$, and $ad-bc \mid g$. So $g = \pm (ad-bc)$. For simplicity let's assume $g = ad-bc$. (If $g = -(ad-bc)$, then either go through a similar argument to the following, or else relabel $(a,b,c,d) \to (c,d,a,b)$, which makes $ad-bc \to cb-da$.)

Now we have $ad-bc = g$. So $(a/g)d - b(c/g) = 1$, where $a/g, d, b, c/g$ all are positive integers.

Finally, consider the combination:
$$
  (-c/g)(an+b) + (a/g)(cn+d) = (-c/g)b + (a/g)d
$$
which equals $1$. Can you finish the proof from here?

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis $\ \delta := ad\!-\!bc\mid a,c,\ $ therefore $\,1 = d(a/\delta)-b(c/\delta)\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{(b,d)\,=\,1}\,$ so by $\rm\color{#0a0}{Euclid}$

$a(cn\!+\!d) -c(an\!+\!b) = \delta$ $\,\Rightarrow\, (an\!+\!b,cn\!+\!d) =\underbrace{(an\!+\!b,cn\!+\!d,\,\color{#0a0}\delta) = (\color{#c00}{b,d},\delta)}_{\!\!\!\large \begin{align}&an+b\ \,\equiv\,\ \color{#c00}b\,\color{#0a0}{\pmod{\!\delta}}\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \delta\ \mid\ a\\ &cn+d\ \,\equiv\,\ \color{#c00}d\,\color{#0a0}{\pmod{\!\delta}}\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \delta\ \mid\ c\end{align} }\!\color{#c00}{ = 1}$

**Or** $\,\ (a/\delta)(cn\!+\!d) -(c/\delta) (an\!+\!b) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, (an\!+\!b,cn\!+\!d)=1\ $ as in the first line.

**Remark** $\ $ We used $\ (k,\delta) = (k',\delta)\ $ if $\ k\equiv k'\color{#0a0}{\pmod{\!\delta}}\,\ $ [i.e. **Euclidean algorithm**]

and further we used $\, (j,k) = (j,k, ak\!-\!cj)\,$ by prior, using $\, ak\!-\!cj\equiv 0\pmod{\!j,k}$

Comment: $(x,y) := \gcd(x,y)\,$ is standard in number theory. $\ \ $

Comment: Are you assuming that $ ad - bc = (a , c) $ ?

Comment: @Octavio I mentioned that in the first version of my answer, but it is not used so I removed it for simplicity.

Comment: All right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers such that
$$
\begin{cases}
(ad - bc){\,|\,}a\\[4pt]
(ad - bc){\,|\,}c
\end{cases}
\qquad
$$
Fix a positive integer $n$.

Let $g=\gcd(an+b,cn+d)$.

Our goal is to show $g=1$.

Let $h=\gcd(a,c)$.

Letting $a_1=a/h$ and $c_1=c/h$, we get
$$
\begin{cases}
a=ha_1\\[4pt]
c=hc_1\\
\end{cases}
\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\;\,
$$
where $a_1,c_1$ are positive integers such that $\gcd(a_1,c_1)=1$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
\begin{cases}
(ad - bc){\,|\,}a\\[4pt]
(ad - bc){\,|\,}c
\end{cases}
\qquad\qquad\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\begin{cases}
(a_1d - bc_1){\,|\,}a_1\\[4pt]
(a_1d - bc_1){\,|\,}c_1
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|a_1d - bc_1|=1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
|ad - bc|=h
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Also, from $|a_1d - bc_1|=1$, we get $\gcd(b,d)=1$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
\begin{cases}
g{\,|\,}(an+b)\\[4pt]
g{\,|\,}(cn+d)\\
\end{cases}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g{\,|\,}\bigl(a(cn+d)-c(an+b)\bigr)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g{\,|\,}(ad-bc)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g{\,|\,}h\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g{\,|\,}a\;\;\text{and}\;\;g{\,|\,}c\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then from $g{\,|\,}a$ and $g{\,|\,}(an+b)$, we get $g{\,|\,}b$.

Similarly, from $g{\,|\,}c$ and $g{\,|\,}(cn+d)$, we get $g{\,|\,}d$.

But then since $\gcd(b,d)=1$, it follows that $g=1$, as was to be shown.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it.