# $a-b,a^2-b^2,a^3-b^3...$ are integers $\implies$ $a,b$ are integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b$ be distinct real numbers such that $a^n -b^n$ is integer for every positive integer $n$ , then is it true that $a,b$ are integers ?

Comment: It is true. It is exercise 19 in [this](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf) pdf on the Lifting The Exponent Lemma. There is a small hint given. If nobody posts a solution I'll do it but actually have to study now ;-)

Comment: Since $a \neq b$, we have that $a + b = \frac{a^2 - b^2}{a - b} \in \mathbb{Q}$. Thus $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ as well. It might be easy to prove past that, but I haven't done it.

Comment: @AlexG. in fact I think $a^n + b^n \in \mathbb{Q}$ for any $n$

Comment: @DanZimm true, but this is obvious since $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Oh right, I feel silly now xD

Comment: @AlexG. It is not true in general that $a+b\in \mathbb{Q}$ implies $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$. Take $a=\pi$ and $b=-\pi$. What else did you use?

Comment: @ThibautDumont however in this case we have that $a+b = \frac{c}{d}$ where $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @ThibautDumont: $a = ((a+b) + (a-b))/2$...

Comment: @poolpt $a + b, a - b \in \mathbb{Q} \implies a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 10):

As many others have noticed, it readily follows that $a,b\in\mathbb Q$. Let $a=\frac cd$ and $b=\frac ef$ such that $\gcd(c,d)=\gcd(e,f)=1$ and $d,f>0$. Writing $\frac cd=z+\frac ef=\frac{fz+e}f$ with $z\in\mathbb Z$, we see that $d=f$.

Note that we have $d^n\mid c^n-e^n$ for every $n$.

I will use the following result, where $\nu_p(n)$ denotes the exponent (possibly $0$) of the prime $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$:

**Lemma.** Let $x$ and $y$ be (not necessarily positive) distinct integers and let $n$ be a positive integer. If $p$ is a prime such that $p\mid x-y$ but $p\nmid n,x,y$, then  $\nu_p(x^n-y^n)=\nu_p(x-y)$.

*Proof.* See [here, Lemma 1](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf) or by using the result from [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247146/how-to-show-that-gcd-left-an-bn-over-a-b-a-b-right-gcdn-dn-1-a-b). As you can see, the proof is elementary and very short.

Now suppose $p$ is a prime divisor of $d$, and let $k=\nu_p(c-e)$.

Consider the integers $n$ that are not divisible by $p$, for example $n=pm+1$. From $d^n\mid c^n-e^n$ and the above lemma it follows that $n\leqslant k$ for all such $n$, which is clearly a contradiction because $n$ can be arbitrarily large.
We conclude that no such $p$ exists. Hence $d=1$, and $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Note that we can avoid considering the prime divisors of $d$, as done in Geoff's answer. However this method alo works when we are only given that $a^n-b^n\in\mathbb Z$ For infinitely many $n$, provided that $a,b\in\mathbb Q$. A stronger analysis of $\nu_p(c^n-e^n)$ is then required, and can be found in the mentioned article.

Comment: The link appears broken; I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is really just the same as barto's, but written up in a more self contained fashion. We may write, as barto has already shown,  $a = \frac{c}{d}, b = \frac{e}{d}$ with $ce$ relatively prime to $d$ and $c,d,e$ integers with $d >0.$ Now for every $d,$ we have $c^{n} \equiv e^{n}$ (mod $d^{n}$). Suppose that $d > 1.$ Then for every integer $n>0,$ we have $c^{n}-e^{n} = (c-e) \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}c^{j}e^{n-1-j}.$ Hence $\frac{c^{n}-e^{n}}{c-e} \equiv nc^{n-1}$ (mod $d$) But $c$ is relatively prime to $d,$ so whenever $n$ is relatively prime to $d,$ we conclude that $\frac{c^{n}-e^{n}}{c-e}$ is relatively prime to $d$. Hence $c-e$ is divisible by $d^{n},$ as $c^{n}-e^{n}$ is, a contradiction, as $d >1$  and $n$ can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Indeed. In fact there is no reason to consider the prime divisors of $d$ as I did. I started thinking about its prime divisors because I had seen the question earlier in the mentioned pdf, so I went looking for a solution using results from that article.

Comment: Your solution was perfectly good.