# $a^n \equiv b^n \pmod{d^n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ implies $a = b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Inspired by [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820421/a-b-a2-b2-a3-b3-are-integers-implies-a-b-are-integers?noredirect=1#comment1695530_820421), I want to prove that if $a, b, d$ are integers such that $a$ and $b$ are coprime to $d$, $d > 1$, and $a^n \equiv b^n \pmod{d^n}$ for every $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ then indeed $a = b$. I think this must be a corollary of some major result from elementary number theory, but I can't find such a result right now.

Comment: why not set $n=1$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That doesn't tell you much unless $d>\lvert a-b\rvert$.

Comment: whoops I misread something there. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $n=1$ we have $a=b+dk$ for some integer $k$.  We now have 
$$d^n|(a^n-b^n)=(b+dk)^n-b^n$$

Hence $(\frac{b}{d}+k)^n-(\frac{b}{d})^n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  We must also have $\frac{b}{d}\notin \mathbb{Z}$ since $\gcd(b,d)=1$.  The result now follows from the question you linked.

Comment: -1 This a mounts a circular proof, since most proofs of the linked theorem reduce to this.

Comment: You must show each step clearly, because its not obvious what you id after "Hence"

Answer (score 1):

A possible major result is the so-called '[Lifting The Exponent Lemma](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf)', as I wrote in my answer to that other question. It is actually a collection of lemma's. I'll restate them, as they are to be found in the above link.

We use the notation $\nu_p(n)$ for the exponent of $p$ (possibly $0$) in the prime factorization of $n$.

**Theorem 1.** Let $x$ and $y$ be (not necessarily positive) integers, let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $p$ be an odd prime such that $p\mid x-y$ and none of $x$ and $y$ is divisible by $p$. We have $\nu_p(x^n-y^n)=\nu_p(x-y)+\nu_p(n)$.

Theorem 2 is an analoguous form for $x^n+y^n$ and $n$ odd, which is easily deduced.

There are two results for the case $p=2$.

**Theorem 3.** Let $x$ and $y$ be two odd integers such that $4\mid x-y$. Then $\nu_2(x^n-y^n)=\nu_2(x-y)+\nu_2(n)$.

and

**Theorem 4.** Let $x$ and $y$ be two odd integers and let $n$ be an even positive integer. Then $\nu_2(x^n-y^n)=\nu_2(x^2-y^2)+\nu_2(n)-1$.

These results prove useful in various number theory problems, and they are worth being memorized.

Comment: The statements of these theorems are better placed not here but in the prior answer where you invoked them (links to external sources always become stale after some point, so you should not depend upon them be persistent).

Comment: Done. Eventually I didn't need them in that other answer.