# The diophantine equation $a^7+b^7=7^c$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Determine all the triples of positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $a^7+b^7=7^c$.

Comment: What do [terns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tern) have to do with it?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should explain its source, include any work you have done, and explain why you are stuck so that we can write answers appropriate to your skill level.

Comment: my bad, i was thinking in italian sorry;

Comment: No problem, [using other languages is encouraged](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19292), but this way it may be a little confusing.

Comment: I was already well advised by N.F.Taussig and i apologize; you think it would make any sense if i re-edit the question after i got answered? maybe yes. Any way next question i will provide more as Taussig was suggesting me.

Comment: See here for the more general [$x^p + y^p = p^z$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217245)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zsigmondy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem) is the way to go. Applying Zsigmondy shows that $a^7+b^7$ has at least $2$ distinct prime divisors (one appearing in the factorisation of $a+b$, the other given by Zsigmondy), hence it can not be a power of $7$.
Of course, Zsigmondy is a bit an overkill here.

A more elementary approach would be to use the result of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247146) (or imitating the proof of the result given there, which isn't too hard):
$$\gcd\left(\frac{a^7+b^7}{a+b},a+b\right)=\gcd(7\gcd(a,b)^6,a+b).$$

If (without loss of generality) $\gcd(a,b)=1$, this would mean that either

- $a+b=7$, which leaves only a few cases to check
- $a+b>7$, in which case the above shows that $\frac{a^7+b^7}{a+b}=7$, hence $a^7+b^7=7(a+b)$ which is impossible if at least one of $a,b$ is $\geqslant2$.

Comment: Either way, I think an approach would be similar to the one in the linked question (binomial expansion and investigating divisibility by powers of $7$ of each of the individual terms) or use some deeper properties of cyclotomic polynomials (as Zsigmondy does). I thought it would be interesting to present some more general results here, because these can be used to solve any equation of this type.

Comment: Note that the second technique does not require FTA nor modular arithmetic.