# Solve $x^p + y^p = p^z$ when $p$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Find the solutions in positive integers of $x^p + y^p = p^z$, where $p$ is a prime number.

Particular case $p=2$:

- For $z=0$ there are no solutions.
- For $z=1$ the only solution is $x=y=1$.
- For $z\ge2$ the solutions are $(x,y,z)$ $(2^k,2^k,2k+1)$.

Now the general case $p \gt 2$:

$p$ is odd 
so $(x + y)(x^{p-1} -x^{p-2}y +...-xy^{p-2} + y^{p-1})= p^z$

being $p$ a prime we have $x + y= p^m$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(-1)^kx^{(p-1)-k}y^k = p^n$ 
with $m + n = z$

Now i'm stuck and nothing come to my mind... also a substitution like $y= p^m -x$ doesn't seem the right path...thanks to those who'll help.

Comment: This has appeared on a French math contest in 2012: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5354

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the well known lemme

> **Lemma 1**: [Lifting The Exponent Lemma (LTE)](http://www.academia.edu/4034266/Lifting_The_Exponent_Lemma_LTE) :Let 
>   $x$ and $y$ be (not necessary positive) integers, let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $p$ be an odd prime such that $p\mid x−y$ and none of $x$ and $y$ is divisible by $p$ (i.e.,$p\not \mid x$ and $p\not \mid y$). then:
>   $$v_p(x^n-y^n)=v_p(x-y)+v_p(n) $$
>
> **Lemma 2**: For very positive integers $x\geq 2$ and $n\geq 2$ we have $x^n\geq nx$ with equality if and only if $x=n=2$ or $x=1$

*Proof* (Lemma 2) using Bernoulli's inequiality we have:
$$x^n=x(1+(x-1))^{n-1}\geq x(1+(x-1)(n-1))\geq x(1+(n-1))=xn $$

Let $x,y,z$ be positive integers and $p$ an odd prime number such that:
$$x^p+y^p=p^z\ \ \ \gcd(x,y)=1$$
Because $z$ is a positive integer and $(x+y)$ divides $x^p+y^p=p^z$ then there exists an integer $m$ such that $x+y=p^m$, using the lemma we have:
$$z=v_p(x^p+y^p)=v_p(x+y)+v_p(p)=v_p(x+y)+1=m+1$$
so we have : $x^p+y^p=p^{m+1}$ and $x+y=p^m$ so two cases :

- If $x\geq 2$ and $y\geq 2$ (and because $p\geq 2$) we can apply lemma $2$ so $x^p\geq px$ and $y^p\geq py$ so that $x^p+y^p\geq p(x+y)$ , but we have equality in this inequality then $p=x=y=2$ which is impossible because of $\gcd(x,y)=1$
- If $x=1$ or $y=1$ we can suppose WLOG that $x=1$ (symmetry of the problem on $x,y$) and therefore $y=p^m-1$ and hence:
  $$p^{m+1}-1=(p^m-1)^p$$
  but we know that $p^{m+1}>p^{m+1}-1=(p^m-1)^p>p^{(m-1)p}$ hence $m+1>(m-1)p$ so $m\leq 1$ so we must have $m=1$  ($m=0$ is impossible) and then $p+1=(p-1)^{(p-1)}$ but this gives us $p=3$ (otherwise $p-1> 2$ and $(p-1)^{p-1}-(p+1)\geq (p-1)^2-(p+1)=p(p-3)>0$)

Now we found all primitive solutions for odd primes $(2,1,2),(1,2,2)$ with $p=3$ which gives the the general solution:
$$(2.3^{k},1.3^{k},3k+2),(3^k,2.3^k,3k+2)$$

Comment: How do you arrive to the inequality?

Comment: I'm sorry there is a mistake in the equality ( first check that $x\neq y$ and then  it's just a generalization of $(x+y)^2\geq 2(x^2+y^2)$ which is true with equality only if $x=y$). I'm sorry I did not explain everything in my answer, but it makes you think and work a little

Comment: Yes,but after getting the contradiction and setting $x$ or $y$ equal to 1 i've to try all the case? i mean for both x and y.

Comment: I will write a complete solution in $10$ minute!(in fact you have to get $(p^{m}-1)^p+1=p^{m+1}$$ but this is not possible)

Comment: I finally complete writing the full solution!

Comment: From your answer i learned tons of things i didn't know (i'm into this kind of problem from very little time) and way more than the others answer,so i mark your question as the one. Just two things: why we can say that x,y are coprime? and how you were able to generalize the solution?

Comment: If $(x,y,z)$ is a general solution to $x^p+y^p=p^z$ then if :$d=gcd(x,y)$ we have $d^p$ divides $p^z$ so we can write $x=ad,y=bd, z'=z-kp, d=p^k$ and from here you can verify that $a^p+b^p=p^{z'}$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and this equation implies $a=1,b=2,p=3,z'=2$ which implies that $x=3^k,y=2.3^k,z=3k+2$ which gives the first solution , and the second one is obtained by symmetry

Answer (score 1):

By [Zsigmondy's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem), if (wlog) $\gcd(x,y)=1$, then $x^p+y^p$ has at least $2$ distinct prime divisors, except for the cases

- $x=y=1$, which gives $(p,x,y,z)=(2,2^k,2^k,2k+1)$
- $2^3+1^3\;\;(=3^2)$, which gives $(p,x,y,z)=(3,2\cdot3^k,3^k,3k+2)$ (and interchanging $x,y$)

Hence these are the only solutions.

Note that solving $x^p+y^p=q^z$ for $p,q$ prime can be done in the same way. The only solutions to this one are the ones already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As$\let\geq\geqslant\let\leq\leqslant$ noted by Elaqqad, the powerful Lifting The Exponent (LTE) gives a quick way out. Here is an approach using a result similar to LTE (but which is easier to prove):

> For $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and $n>1$, $$ \gcd\left( \frac{a^n-b^n }{ a-b} ,a-b\right)=\gcd(n\gcd(a,b)^{n-1},a-b ). $$
>   Proof: [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247146) (or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/660329/43288) for the most beautiful proof).

It's certainly worth being remembered. I call it *'LTE in divisibility form'* because it's almost as strong as the actual LTE but it can be formulated and proved without using modular arithmetic.

---

Wlog we can assume $\gcd(x,y)=1$. If $p$ is odd, we have
$$ \gcd\left( \frac{x^p+y^p}{x+y},x+y\right)=\gcd(p,x+y).$$

Because $x+y$ is a power of $p$, we either have

- $x+y=p$. If $p$ is known, this gives only finitely many cases to check. If $p$ is arbitrary, you may want to use a LTE-type argument (though you don't need its full power) here to conclude that $z=2$, giving $x^p+y^p=p^2$.
  But $$x^p+y^p\geq x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x\cdot(x-y)+y\cdot y)\geq(x+y)(x+y)=p^2$$ (when $x\geq y$) with equality only for $p=3$, $x-y=1$ and $y=1$.
- $x+y>p$ and $\frac{x^p+y^p}{x+y}=p$. Same story: $$x^p+y^p\geq x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x\cdot(x-y)+y\cdot y)\geq(x+y)(x+y)>p(x+y),$$ contradiction.

Summarizing, we have $(p,x,y,z)=(3,2\cdot3^k,3^k,3k+2)$.

Note that this doesn't work for $p=2$ because then we can't change the minus-sign into a plus in that one $\gcd$ identity. Luckily the case $p=2$ isn't too hard: If (wlog) $\gcd(x,y)=1$, then $x,y$ are odd and hence $x^2+y^2\equiv2\pmod4$, hence $z=1$. Adding factors $2$ eventually gives $(p,x,y,z)=(2,2^k,2^k,2k+1)$.

---

**Note:** this does not provide a solution to $x^p+y^p=q^z$ for $p,q$ prime, whereas Elaqqad's LTE-approach and the Zsigmondy-approach do.