# Solve $x^n+z^n=(x+1)^n$ for $n\ge 3$ without FLT

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there a way to prove that for $x,z,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x > 0$, $z > 0$, $n > 2$, the equation

$$ x ^ n + z ^ n = (x + 1) ^ n $$

has no solution, **without** using Fermat's Last Theorem?

Best regards

Comment: Related: [Solve $(x+1)^n-x^n=p^m$ in positive integers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235875) and [Solve $n^s-(n-1)^t=1$ for $n,s,t>0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215862)

Comment: I have edited the question with an equivalent equation.

Comment: We may assume that $n=4$, or $n=p>2$ is prime. Then see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2628675/simple-method-of-solution-of-xpyp-x1p?noredirect=1).