# Simple Method of Solution of $X^p+Y^p=(X+1)^p$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am looking for simple prove of non existence of solution of $$X^p+Y^p=(X+1)^p$$
for $p>2$
I know it is partial case of Fermat Last Theorem. But I am looking for simple method without going into the complex part of group theory and algebra.
I have simply found from the Fermat Little Theorem that $$Y\equiv1\pmod p$$
But this the maximum I was able to get. Is there any idea how to solve this using simple methods?

Comment: Are you trying to prove the equation has **no** solutions for $X,Y$ integers and $p$ prime?

Comment: Just have edited question, sorry.

Comment: Of course, my previous comment is silly but it's too late to edit it.  I meant to say $(X+1-Y)|X.$

Comment: Do you want to show that it is not possible for some $p > 2$ or do you want to show that it is not possible for all $p > 2$?

Comment: For all $p>2$. In other words prove the Fermat Last Theorem  for (X,Y,X+1) case. but using simple method.

Comment: I see. I was confused because you used Fermat's little theorem which requires $p$ to be prime.

Comment: I just mentioned $p$ prime as if we prove for prime this is the same as to prove for any odd number.

Comment: @saulspatz Why is $x\equiv0\pmod p$ necessarily true? For $p=13$, $13^2\mid(3+1)^{13}-3^{13}-1$ but $13\not\mid3$ nor $13\not\mid3+1$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Yes, as I noted earlier, that was a silly comment.  Look at the comment just after it.

Comment: $Y=X-pk+n$,
$(X-pk+n)^p≡(X+n)^p≡ 1 \mod p$
$⇔X^p+n^p≡1 ⇒X+n≡0 \mod p$

, on the other side $Y ≡0 \mod p^p$. Then requirement is just $(X+1)^p-X^p \neq 0 \mod {p^2}$.

Comment: Sorry what is the $n$ in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an open question. See *Fermat’s Last Theorem for Amateurs* by Paulo Ribenboim. Specifically following results of Catalan are shown:

> For $p$ odd prime number, $0<x<y$ integers such that $x^p+y^p=(y+1)^p$, the following is true:
>
> 1. $py(y+1)$ divides $x^p-1$
> 2. $p\nmid x$,  $p\mid x-1$
> 3. If $q$ is a prime dividing $y+1-x$ then $q$ divides $x-1$
> 4. $\gcd(x+y,y+1-x)=1$
> 5. $\gcd(2x-1,2y+1)=1$
> 6. $x$ is the only integer such that $(py^{p-1})^{1/p} < x < (p(y+1)^{p-1})^{1/p}$

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** This proof is **incorrect**.  The calculations are right, I think, but then I jump to a completely unjustified (and untrue) conclusion at the end.  My inclination is to delete this answer, but I'm leaving it at the request of the OP.

I think I know how to do this.  I'll just give you my idea, and let you fill in the details.

As you said, $Y \equiv 1 \pmod p,$ and as I remarked in my comments, we know $X \equiv 0 \pmod p.$ Write $X=px, Y=py+1,$ and expand the equation by the binomial theorem.$$\begin{align}p^px^p + \sum_{k=0}^p{\binom{p}{k}p^ky^k}&=\sum_{k=0}^p{\binom{p}{k}p^kx^k}\\ \sum_{k=1}^p{\binom{p}{k}p^ky^k}&=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{\binom{p}{k}p^kx^k}\end{align}$$ 
Here we have subtracted $p^px^p$ from the sum on the right, subtracted the $k = 0$ term from both sums.(Many thanks to **user159517** who pointed out the need for this step.)

Now I claim that $p^3$ divides the coefficient of each of these terms, except the $k=1$ terms.  When $k=1$ the coefficient is $p^2.$  When $k\ge 3$ the coefficient is obviously divisible by $p^3.$  When $k=2,$ the coefficient is $$\binom{p}{2}p^2 = \frac{p(p-1)p^2}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod {p^3},$$
since $p$ is an odd prime.

Now dividing through by $p^2$ and reducing both sides mod $p$ gives $x \equiv y \pmod p$ since all term with $k>1$ vanish.  Now we can say $Y \equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}\text{ and }X \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}.$ (**No we can't!  This is FALSE even in the case $x=y$.**) It should be possible to prove by induction that $Y \equiv 1 \pmod {p^n}\text{ and }X \equiv 0 \pmod {p^n}$ for every $n,$  thus proving $X=0, Y=1.$

**EDIT** Example for $p=3,$ requested by OP.

In this case, we have $X=3x, Y=3y+1,$ so our equation becomes $$\begin{align}(3x)^3+(3y+1)^3 &= (3x+1)^3\\27x^3+27y^3+27y^2+9y+1 &=27x^3+27x^2+9x+1\\27y^3+27y^2+9y&=27x^2+9x\\3y^3+3y^2+y&=3x^2+x\\y &\equiv x \pmod 3\end{align}$$

Comment: @user159517 Duh, you're right.  Perhaps it can be fixed it by subtracting the the last terms, and dividing through by $p$.  I was sitting here puzzling about why I hadn't $p>2$ and you've probably put your finger on it.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for response, I am trying to solve it from your observation. I think there will be simpler way without induction. I will come back with solution soon I hope.

Comment: Could you please illustrate this for the case $p=3$. This will be very helpful.

Comment: Many thanks for providing the case for $p=3$ could you please just add one more step with proving of $Y \equiv 1 \pmod {3^2}\text{ and }X \equiv 0 \pmod {3^2}.$

Comment: That's false.  It seemed so clear yesterday, but I was obviously muddled.  I need to think about whether this line of attack can be rescued at all.  I apologize profusely if I've just been wasting your time.  I'll either fix the proof of delete the answer.

Comment: Your answer contains valuable details, so please keep it, I just saw this issue with $p=3$ case this is why I mentioned this. You can just remove the incorrect part, but please keep the answer.