# If $(a,b)=1$ and n is prime then prove that $\frac{a^n+b^n}{a+b}$ and $a+b$ have no common factor unless $a+b$ is a multiple of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I assumed the GCD of both numbers is $d$ and it's evident that $d|a+b$ and $d|a^n+b^n$

But now I don't have any idea how to  move further.Any suggestions??
 Note : this question is asked from a elementary guide to number theory.so I highly recommend to use only elementary properties of GCD to prove

Comment: For odd $n,$ $$b^n=-(-b)^n$$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247146/show-that-gcd-left-fracan-bna-b-a-b-right-gcdn-dn-1-a-b

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Let $c=a+b$ and
$$d=\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}=a^{p-1}-a^{p-2}b+a^{p-3}b^2-\cdots+b^{p-1}.$$
If $q\ne p$ is a prime factor of both $c$ and $d$, then $b\equiv -a\pmod q$
and so
$$0\equiv d\equiv a^{p-1}+a^{-p-1}+\cdots+a^{p-1}=pa^{p-1}\pmod q.$$
Then $a\equiv0\pmod q$, and $b\equiv-a\equiv0\pmod q$ contradicting $\gcd(a,b)=1$.