# Induction on GCD problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

This is a two part question

Given $\gcd(a,b) = 1$

consider 
$$\gcd \left( \frac{a^n - b^n }{a-b}, a- b\right) $$

It appears that the value of this is always equal to $n$ or $1$. How to prove it?

And with that show

$$\gcd \left( \frac{a^n - b^n }{a-b}, a- b\right) = \gcd \left( n \frac{a^{n-1} - b^{n-1}}{a-b}, a- b \right) $$

I began with tackling the first part

I trie to use an Inductive Proof at first by noting:

$$\frac{a^{n+1} - b^{n+1}}{a-b} = a\frac{a^{n} - b^{n}}{a-b} + b^{n} = b\frac{a^{n} - b^{n}}{a-b} + a^{n} $$

But this didn't pan out any sort of solution since it doesn't become immediately apparent that $n+1$ divides this new quantity or some linear combination of this quantity with $a - b$

I could attempt a combinatorial approach and ty to use the binomial theorem I was thinking. But no apparent way to match terms become apparent.

What should I do for the first part?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247146/how-to-show-that-gcd-left-an-bn-over-a-b-a-b-right-gcdn-dn-1-a-b

Comment: Is this true? Take a= 6, b= 3 and n=2. Then gcd (9,3) = 3 which is neither 2 nor 1!

Comment: @Manasi not sure how you came to that conclusion. What is your choice of exponent $n$?

Comment: @Manasi It's true if $\,d = (a,b) = 1.\,$ Otherwise it involves $\,d\,$ also, see the above link, or follow my hint. This has been asked many times before.

Comment: Ah @Manasi i see $n = 2$ works

Comment: @frogeyedpeas : Yes.

Comment: @BillDubuque : Yeah, your statement seems like standard matter which I need to verify but the OP has not mentioned anything about the gcd being only 1!

Comment: @BillDubuque True if $d=(a,b)=1$, then that link shows it is $\gcd(n,a-b)$, not "$1$ or $n$." That's only true when $n$ is prime.

Comment: @Manasi Yes, but the statement just isn't true in general, so what the OP wants is wrong. :)

Comment: @Thomas Yes, that's correct. I misremembered what I read in  the question.

Comment: Alright People... You got me! They were supposed to be coprime! :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: yeah,agreed! I referred to BD's statement and not OP's.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas : Hey, I am NOT* a gentleman (period) and will not be for the rest of my life...

Comment: Forgive me Manasi, let me edit that previous comment :)

Comment: @frogeyedpeas : It is okay, ha ha...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sometimes it's annoying when your memory "auto-corrects" errors. Have you ever had that happen? It reminds me of the classical studies on chess and cognition (DeGroot?) where they presented positions to grandmasters for memorization. They were able to reconstruct meaningful positions with high accuracy, but did very poorly with random boards (their memory often "corrected" the random boards into something more meaningful), iirc (w/o auto-error-correction!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ \big(x\!-\!a,\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\!\big) = (x\!-\!a,\:f'(a))\,\ $ by $\ \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}  \equiv f'(a)\pmod{\!x\!-\!a}\ $ for $\ f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$

For further details see [my post here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6310/n-mid-an-bn-longrightarrow-n-mid-fracan-bna-b/6448#6448) which elaborates on how this result is a *number*-theoretical analog of a well-known result about *functions* (polynomials), viz. about multiplicity of roots.

Comment: I think this is probably far more advanced than what I was expected to use, but damn... thats a very interesting identity there. I don't think I've seen calculus and number theory intersect that curiously before

Comment: @frogeyedpeas It uses only  an *infinitesimal* amount of calculus, viz. differentiation of polynomials, which can actually be *defined* purely algebraically by the above congruence.

Answer (score 0):

If $D$ is the GCD, then $a\equiv b\pmod D$, and therefore:

$$0\equiv  \frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^kb^{n-1-k} \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^{n-1} = na^{n-1}\pmod D$$

So $D\mid na^{n-1}$. Since $D\mid a-b$ and $(a-b,a)=1$, you have:
$$D\mid n$$

On the other hand, it is easy to show the converse, that if $d\mid a-b$ and $d\mid n$ then $d\mid \frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$.

So $D=\gcd(n,a-b)$.